# xdebug track / trace php echo, print calls

Tags: php, debugging, printing, echo, xdebug

Is there a way to see echo or print function calls in xdebug trace output. I am looking for a global configuration (or a way to do that) for all scripts that I run in my server.

Example:

```
<?php 
  echo "xdebug show me";
?>
```

I want trace output to show echo call.  By default it is not shown. I tried disabling output buffer (which may not be relevant) but did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have the same problem at hand. The xdebug function trace doesn't show traces of echo, print_r etc,  which are language constructs. I would appreciate if there is any workaround or a trick in the xdebug config to show those functions in the trace.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a 100% sure, but I think profiling the script might give you the information. XDebug has the ability to profile your application. This will log every call (including the execution time). You should be able to retrieve the information from this dump file.

See http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler for more information.

Comment: It doesn't log calls to `echo`